Which android applications use Google recaptcha to identify real users from bot
As stated in documentation - reCAPTCHA is a free service that uses an advanced risk analysis engine to protect your app from spam and other abusive actions. If the service suspects that the user interacting with your app might be a bot instead of a human, it serves a CAPTCHA that a human must solve before your app can continue executing.
Does anyone knows some android applications which uses Google recaptcha
I am trying to add captcha for my app, wanted to other apps if they use it

To learn how to integration reCAPTCHA into your Android app please see these docs. As far as which, or how many, apps currently use this integration that is impossible to know.

Yes but i wanted to know does any android app shows "Captcha" as far as i have explored only websites or web apps show captcha

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
